# Can't run programs created in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt-creator

When I run a release build of a program I made in Qt Creator, it says it can't find a DLL.
So I added all the DLLs from the Qt `bin` folder into the program directory, and now the program doesn't come up with an error, but it doesn't start anyways?

I didn't change any of the compiler settings in Qt Creator, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the program start when you run it from Qt Creator in Release build?

Comment: I suspect you are talking about Qt Creator, the IDE, and edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: "It doesn't start"? can u show the code?

Comment: What kind of project did you run? GUI or console? If it is a console application without keyboard interrupt it might disappear very fast.

Comment: It runs if i start a program by clicking the green arrow in QT creator, it doesn't work if i compile it and open the .exe file from the folder.

Comment: Yes, it will not run, because it can't find the qt libs (e.g. libQtCore.so/dll). You either have to compile qt statically as duDE answered, or you extract the libs you need to your executable and append it to your PATH variable.

Comment: See this answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14703874/1717300

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to compile QT statically:

http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Building_static_Qt_on_Windows

Comment: Screw it, I'm just gonna copy every single DLL file to get it to work.

Comment: add Qt libs path into your PATH environment variable

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Qt4, this explains what .DLL files are needed (same document, two links for future-proofing the answer):

- http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/deployment-windows.html#shared-libraries
- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html#shared-libraries

If you are using Qt5, it's a bit more complicated (right plugins are *required* in the right sub-folder under the .EXE directory), and I don't know if there's a document for that written yet...

Answer (score 0):

I stuck icudt49.dll,icuin49.dll,icuuc49.dll,libEGL.dll,libGLESv2,Qt5Core.dll,Qt5Gui.dll and Qt5Widgets.dll in the same directory as the Exe file, and it works (all these files are needed for it to work) (This is for the release version)