# Exe file does not run without QtCreator

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt-quick, qtquick2

I installed **Qt 5.0.1 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.7, 823 MB)**

Then I created simple Quick 2 application and compiled it. Application is located in the its folder, and apllication run from QtCreator. And I want to run this exe file without QtCreator. To do this, I copy the files from the **C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin**:

1. Qt5Core.dll
2. icuin49.dll
3. libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll
4. libwinpthread-1.dll
5. libGLESv2.dll
6. libstdc++-6.dll
7. qminimal.dll
8. Qt5Gui.dll
9. Qt5Network.dll
10. Qt5Qml.dll
11. Qt5Quick.dll
12. Qt5V8.dll
13. qwindows.dll

And then I get error:

**Точка входа в процедуру _ZN6icu_4910CharString15getAppendBufferEiiRiR10UErrorCode не найдена в библиотеке DLL icuuc49.dll**

Translate:

**The procedure entry point _ZN6icu_4910CharString15getAppendBufferEiiRiR10UErrorCode not found in library DLL icuuc49.dll**

If I copy the exe file to a folder **C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin** (where are all the dll), the program runs, but nothing shows.

If I copy the exe file to a folder **C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin** (where are all the dll), the program does not run.

What to do? Where and what libraries to take the program to run?

**Solved.** The final list of libraries from **C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin**:

1. icuin49.dll
2. icuuc49.dll
3. libEGL.dll
4. libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll
5. libGLESv2.dll
6. libstdc++-6.dll
7. libwinpthread-1.dll
8. Qt5Core.dll
9. Qt5Gui.dll
10. Qt5Network.dll
11. Qt5Qml.dll
12. Qt5Quick.dll
13. Qt5V8.dll

And I forgot to add the folder with qml files.

Comment: OH MY GOD. Computer science exam tomorrow, I was thinking I would never get it done thanks to this bloody problem. Solved! I cannot thank you enough!!!!!!

Comment: This issue is resolved in following link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058342/application-doesnot-launch-created-using-msvc2010solved

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Put your executable in a neutral directory, like a freshly created one your desktop. Then run [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). It will show you the list of missing libraries. For a start `Qt5Core.dll`, `libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll` and the one you specified will be one of the missing. You have to find them on your system, and copy one by one to this directory. Most of the missing will be in the directory you specified (`C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin`). If you cannot find the other ones edit the question with a list.

**Note:**
Types of missing files in the General case :

- Qt libraries. If Qt was compiled as static, they should not appear
- Misc libraries Qt depends on : OpenSSL for example. Not appearing if both Qt and this lib is static
- Compiler libraries : ex, gcc `libgcc_s_sjlj` for the OP. They are usually dynamic and need to be copied if they are not already in the library search path.

Comment: I updated list of using dll, but program has problems with run.  Dependency walker shows that the error that I described: _ZN6icu_4910CharString15getAppendBufferEiiRiR10UErrorCode

When I copy all dll from *C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin* and from *C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\plugins\platforms* programs run, but nothing shows.

Comment: Thank you so much! Dependency walker has helped to find the dll`s. And I forgot to add the folder with qml files. The final list of libraries: icuin49.dll, icuuc49.dll, libEGL.dll, libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll, libGLESv2.dll, libstdc++-6.dll, libwinpthread-1.dll, Qt5Core.dll, Qt5Gui.dll, Qt5Network.dll, Qt5Qml.dll, Qt5Quick.dll, Qt5V8.dll.

Comment: There's also an alternative to dependency walker for the Qt-Libraries. It's called windeployqt you can find it at QTDIR/bin/windeployqt. It is explained  on the bottom of this page: [http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html)

Answer (score -3):

Add "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin" to your path. Then the application should work.

Comment: Terrible idea.  If you are trying to launch this outside of Creator, you are probably trying to make/test a deployable copy.

Answer (score -4):

Dont worry about the missing dll files.
put your .exe file into the folder of this path : "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin"

you can run the .exe file now . it works fine.

Comment: I would not put applications in bin folders of other applications... For testing yeah, but it's not a solution to the problem.

Comment: While it might be possible to get the run the app there, it definitely is not possible to ship a Qt distribution with every executable. As explained above the right way to do it is to solve all dependencies.

Comment: Do not do this unless you are merely trying to run this on your own machine (and don't want to click the execute button in Creator for whatever reason).  This won't help make a deployable.