# QT 5 Creator INclude required DLL's in Executable

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qt-creator, qt5

I have created a simple file copy program that I would like to run as a stand alone executable.
However when I run it outside Qtcreator I get a Qt5Core.dll is not found error.
I have found some stuff about copying the dll to the same folder as the executable or compiling staticly, but I have had no luck with this.

Is there a way to embed all the required dll's n the executable?
Preferably with the .pro file

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exe file does not run without QtCreator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702879/exe-file-does-not-run-without-qtcreator)

Comment: I believe compiling statically will solve me issue, but I have not been able to figure out how to compile statically.

Comment: compiling statistically will be an overkill. You just need to find the location of the messing libraries and put them into the folder where your executable is. The procedure is available in the link above.

Comment: I would like the executable to be standalone, so that if I need to copy it to another machine I won't have to copy a folder I can just copy the file.

Comment: This is all covered in great detail in the Qt documentation here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/windows-deployment.html