# How to create exe file in qt designer with visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, exe, qt-designer

I create a qt application in visual studio. After building the project , the `exe` file not running and I have error message for missing a lot of `dll` files  such as `Qt5Core.dll` and the others.
How can I fix it?

Comment: your answer is here [link]. You could find it with simple search. [link]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702879/exe-file-does-not-run-without-qtcreator

Comment: Tank you for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exe file does not run without QtCreator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702879/exe-file-does-not-run-without-qtcreator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let suppose your exe file name in `MyApp.exe`.

- copy `MyApp.exe` in a new folder. for example `myfolder`.
- open `myfolder` press shift and right click at myfolder's window
- in opened right click menu select `Open command window here`
- execute `C:\Qt\Qt5.9.3\5.9.3\msvc2015_64\bin\windeployqt.exe MyApp.exe`

**note that** `C:\Qt\Qt5.9.3\5.9.3\msvc2015_64` path is depend on your installed qt version and it's directory.